# How to run a dynamic project with Polymer project?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have just started working on Polymer Project and I am having some difficulties in identifying what could be done with Polymer Project. So my question is: Is it possible to do a dynamic website using Polymer? My project needs to be connected to a database.
I'm working on Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
Prime Examples are: Google Play Music and Google I/O

More can be found on the [Built With Polymer website](http://builtwithpolymer.org/)